# Removing configured PROXY in fedora?

Tags: fedora, yum, proxy

Some time back I configured proxy for fedora to install packages through yum.
I forgot how exactly I did it.

Now I don't need proxy any more.How can I reconfigure my proxy settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, you set up the proxy in `/etc/yum.conf`, with the `proxy` setting.